# Run Spark job with properties files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, properties-file

As a beginner of stack Hadoop, I would like to run my Spark job with spark-submit via Oozie. Having an jar including src compiling project files, I have also a set of properties files (about 20). I want that, when running my spark Job, we can load these properties files from a different folder beside the folder including my Spark Job compiled jar. I've tried:

- In my job.properties of oozie, I added:
  oozie.libpath=[path to the folder including all of my properties files]
  and oozie.use.system.libpath=true.
- on the spark-submit command, I added --files or --properties-file but it's not working (It doesn't accept the folder)

Thanks for any suggestions or feel free to ask more if my question is not clear.

Comment: is this shell action? in properties-file are you setting hdfs path?